# How do I get my sidebar to align with the text to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I"m trying to replicate this codepen but with my own code. However, I have no idea how to get my sidebar to line to the right side. I don't get it. I understand the difference between inline block vs blocks but why cannot I get my sidebar to line up to the right. I want the side bar to start just a little above the text on the right side of the page.

I have made a imageText div and aligned the image and paragraph text to the left side of the page hence I figured that would help align the side bar to the right side of the page. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a div for the side bar which I understand puts the sidebar on a new line but even if i remove it, it does not line up with the image and text. If i use inline block it just lines it under the text. If I set the position to absolute, it still does not allow me to line up the side bar to the right side of the page near the text.  I'm trying to get a good grasp of the basics of HTML/CSS.  this is an assignment on Udemy. Please see my code

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
}

.myWebsite {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.imageText {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

img {
  /*   width: 350px; */
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 280px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block
}

/* .footer{
 border: 2px solid yellow;
margin: 20px;
} */
```

```html
<div class="myWebsite">
  <h2>My Website </h2>
  <a class="nav" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#about">About</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="imageText">
  <img src="https://www.surfertoday.com/images/stories/surferbarrel.jpg">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis
    imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Some Useful Articles</a>
</div>

<!-- <footer class="footer">
  <p>Join our mailing List</p>
 <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up!" />
</footer> -->

</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/mbowen/pen/epBgaJ

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the css and bit of html to achieve your goal.
Basically, you want your sidebar to me right aligned with your image and text.
For that, encapsulate both all your elements inside a parent div. Make the div and and all its contents inline-block. And then make all children float left and just set their width.
In below code i have set the image and image text container width as 75% and the sidebar width as 25%. This makes them total cover a full width of 100%. Therefore your sidebar will always be at last, i.e., right aligned for all screens. You can use additional media queries to set the width of elements according to different screen sizes.

Please see you can also make use of CSS FlexBox. That is more easier with less CSS.
Hope it helps. :)

```css
body, body *{
box-sizing: border-box;

}
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
}

.myWebsite {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.imageText {
  width: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 280px;
  width: 25%;
}

.myContainer{
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 100px;
}
.myContainer *{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="myWebsite">
  <h2>My Website </h2>
  <a class="nav" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#about">About</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="myContainer">
<div class="imageText">

  <img src="https://www.surfertoday.com/images/stories/surferbarrel.jpg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis
    imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Some Useful Articles</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `.imageText`, and the `.sidebar` with an element (I've used `<main`), and set it's display to `flex`:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
}

.myWebsite {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.imageText {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

img {
  /*   width: 350px; */
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 280px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block
}

main {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

/* .footer{
 border: 2px solid yellow;
margin: 20px;
} */
```

```html
<div class="myWebsite">
  <h2>My Website </h2>
  <a class="nav" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#about">About</a>
  <a class="nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<main>

  <div class="imageText">
    <img src="https://www.surfertoday.com/images/stories/surferbarrel.jpg">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce
      luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed
      nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#">Some Useful Articles</a>
  </div>

</main>

<!-- <footer class="footer">
  <p>Join our mailing List</p>
 <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up!" />
</footer> -->

</body>

</html>
```